# SOLR OR query behaving like an AND QUERY

Tags: solr

Running a SOLR OR query `(end_date=* | start_date!=*)`, it is behaving as an `AND` query and returning no results. If I run each query separately, it return results for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. This code `(end_date=* | start_date!=*)`

gets converted into a `Solr` syntax

`(end_date:[* TO *] OR -start_date:[* TO *])` `note "-" negation`

which in my testing data both `start_date` and `end_date` either had values or didn't have values which is why it was returning no results.

Answer (score 2):

The [OR operator in The Standard Query Parser in Solr](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser#TheStandardQueryParser-BooleanOperatorsSupportedbytheStandardQueryParser) is either `OR` (in caps) or `||`. I'm not sure if the query you're using is correct either (if you're checking for whether a field exists, [* TO *] is the usual way of doing that).